# Changing the objects position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uilabel

Let's say I have a single-view project and there I have a square `UILabel`.
I crate a simple timer with time interval of 0.05 seconds.

It launches a void method which has the following code:

```
obj.center = CGPointMake(150+(80*cos(0.25*t)), 150+(80*sin(0.25*t)));
obj.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", t];

UIImageView *dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150+(80*cos(0.25*t)),150+(80*sin(0.25*t)),20,20)];
dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"];
[self.view addSubview:dot];

t++;
```

(where (150;150) is the center of a circle path, 80 is the radius of it and (0.25*t) is used to change the angle as the time goes on)

As you can see, it changes the label's position, so that it moves along the circular path. And also I wanted it to create some `UIImage` right at the `UILabel` position, so that they will mark the trajectory.

The problem is that the label is going round OR the `UIImage` are created, forming the circle ONLY if they are used separately. If I use both lines of code for `UILabel` and for `UIImage` - than the label remains at the center of the circle path, while the images are created around it.

I tried using the label's X/Y coordinates to create images, and also I tried to create a detached method `drawCircle`. The result is still the same.

If only the label is told to go round - it does so, else it stays in the center.

Comment: could it be a refresh or display order problem? What happens if you place the image first and then move obj? Possibly set the obj to front after setting the UIImage `[view bringSubviewToFront:obj]`?

Comment: Tried both - changing the order of actions doesn't help, nor does the bringSubviewToFornt. The UILabel still stays in the center of the newly created UIImages circle.

Comment: are you doing all this in the main thread?

Comment: Looks to me like you are better of subclassing `UIView`.

Comment: @Neva Yeah, in the viewDidLoad I create a timer, add it to the main loop, then it executes the same method all over again.